# How can I set the contentType of a blob on Azure using azure-cli?

Tags: azure, command-line

I am trying to update the contentType of an uploaded file or at least be able to reupload a file with the correct contentType.

In my case I am uploading css but it gives it a content type of application/octet-stream by default.

The command line reference doesn't show how to manage the properties of a blob as far as I can tell

**Edit**

If you just create the file apparently you can use

`azure storage blob create -f {file_name} -p contentType=text/css`

But I still haven't found a way to edit one yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can now set blob properties using [`az storage blob update`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/storage/blob#az-storage-blob-update) from the [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/) ([source on GitHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli)).  For example, to set the `Content-Type` of a blob named `$blob` in a container named `$container` to `text/css`:

```
az storage blob update -c "$container" -n "$blob" --content-type text/css
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source code [`here`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-xplat-cli/blob/master/lib/commands/asm/storage.blob._js), I don't think it is possible to update blob's properties using azure-cli.

If you're interested, you can use [`Node SDK for Azure Storage`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-node) and update blob properties. For example, look at the sample code below:

```
var AZURE = require('azure-storage');
var blobService = AZURE.createBlobService("<account name>", "<account key>");
var container = '<blob container name>';
var blob = '<blob name>';
var newContentType = '<new content type e.g. text/css>'
blobService.getBlobProperties(container, blob, function(error, result, response) {
    if (!error) {
        var contentType = result.contentType;
        var cacheControl = result.cacheControl;
        var contentEncoding = result.contentEncoding;
        var contentMD5 = result.contentMD5;
        var contentLanguage = result.contentLanguage;
        var options = {
            'contentType': newContentType,
            'cacheControl': cacheControl,
            'contentEncoding': contentEncoding,
            'contentMD5': contentMD5,
            'contentLanguage': contentLanguage,
        };
        blobService.setBlobProperties(container, blob, options, function(error, result, response) {
            if (!error) {
                console.log('Properties updated successfully!');
            } else {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });     
    } else {
        console.log(error);
    }
});
```